# How to show error message next to input field-service portal

Tags: jquery, angularjs, servicenow

I am trying to show an error message next to my input field

```
g_form.showFieldMsg('request_type','Low impact not allowed with High 
priority','error');
```

It working good.

Now I want to add a link instead of text in an error box

```
var link='<a href="/aaa"></a>'
g_form.showFieldMsg('request_type',link,'error');
```

Its displaying like this in an error box

```
'<a href="/aaa"></a>'
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
g_form.showFieldMsg('number_of_servers_lenovo',"Enter a numeric value for \'Servers - Lenovo\' field.",'error');
```

This will work .